# Как реализовать ожидание асинхронного действия?

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-vksdk

Есть приложение, которое работает с VKSDK. Я делаю запросы к вк (знаю точное их кол-во), но они приходят с некоторой задержкой + еще зависит от интернета на устройство.

**Вопрос:** как правильно реализовать ожидание того момента, когда приложение получит все данные?

Первое, что приходит в голову - в потоке, где происходят запросы создать переменную, которая будет увеличиваться после каждого получения данных. Если 50 запросов, то когда переменная станет равна 50, это значит, что все данные получены. В то же время создать дополнительный поток, который будет крутиться в цикле и проверять увеличивающуюся переменную. Когда поток увидит, что переменная стала равна 50, то он завершает цикл и запускает следующий метод.

Но что-то мне подсказывает, что это неверный подход и всё это можно сделать проще и правильнее.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие инструменты мне нужно использовать для этого?

Comment: Нужно именно параллельное выполнение запросов?

Comment: Тут RxJava помочь может)

Comment: @eugeneek нет, запросы происходят последовательно. Когда все запросы отправлены и данные получены, тогда следует выполнить следующий метод.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, я тоже подумал про observeon/observable, но я еще не использовал это. Хотелось увидеть как это делали ПРАВИЛЬНО до RxJava, но, судя по всему, придется разбираться с RxJava :)

Comment: @Denis422, я сам не знаю как правильно было до RxJava, но, судя по всему, это было так ужасно, что проще было `RxJava` написать и её использовать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб понял, спасибо. Ответ получен, буду разбираться.

Comment: Раз последовательно, то просто начинайте каждый новый запрос в колбеке от предыдущего. Это так делалось до RxJava. И называется callback hell =)